# extracting data from excel to matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose i have an excel file (data.xlsx) , which contains the following data.

```
Name   age
Tom    43 
Dick   24
Harry  32
```

Now i want to extract the data from it and make 2 cell array (or matrix) which shall contain

> name = ['Tom' ; 'Dick';'Harry']
>   age = [43;24;32]

i have used `xlsread(data.xlsx)` , but its only extracting the numerical values ,but i want to obtain both as mentioned above . Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

You have to use additional output arguments from [xlread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) in order to get the text.

I created a dummy Excel file with your data and here is the output (nevermind about the NaNs):

```
[ndata, text, alldata] = xlsread('DummyExcel.xlsx')

ndata =

    43
    24
    32


text = 

    'Name'     'Age'
    'Tom'      ''   
    'Dick'     ''   
    'Harry'    ''   


alldata = 

    [NaN]    'Name'     'Age'
    [NaN]    'Tom'      [ 43]
    [NaN]    'Dick'     [ 24]
    [NaN]    'Harry'    [ 32]
```

Now if you use this:

```
 text{2:end,1}
```

you get

```
ans =

Tom


ans =

Dick


ans =

Harry
```

Comment: Thanks , but i need to store them in a single cell array or matrix . Is there any possible way for it ?

Comment: yes they will already be stored in the cell array 'text'. You can play around with 'alldata' to retrieve what you need. Since everything is in a cell array it will be quite simple

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function called [importdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html).

Example:

```
%Import Data
filename = 'yourfilename.xlsx';
delimiterIn = ' ';
headerlinesIn = 1;
A = importdata(filename,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
```

This will help to take both the text data and numerical data. Textdata will be under A.textdata and numerical data will be under A.data.